# Obtain with random search only the dates that correspond to present data

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datetimepicker

My code looks for me only on Saturdays, but in random it also looks for Saturdays that are not present in my table, for example Saturday November 2nd, I have no data, I would like it to skip those dates that have no data to display in DataGridView. So when randomizing the datatimepichker, I would like it to skip those dates or Saturdays that don't match anything in my table and then move past that is to next Saturday, until it finds the date that matches a full row and not null. 2
With a button, I created the possibility to search through 2 DateTimePicker (1 and 2) the targeted search, in this case only on Saturdays, of data that I have in the table and that I display with a DataGridView.

What I would like is that in the random of Saturdays, it passes over when the Saturday does not correspond to the data present in the DataGridView.

How do I do this?

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub btnSabatoVecchio_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSabatoVecchio.Click
    d1.Value = GetRandomDate(d1.MinDate, d1.MaxDate)
    Dim table As New DataTable()
    Dim command As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM LottoDeaBendata WHERE [Data] BETWEEN @d1 AND @d2", connection)
    d1.Value = d1.Value.AddDays(DayOfWeek.Sunday - (d1.Value.DayOfWeek + 1))
    d2.Value = d1.Value
    command.Parameters.Add("@d1", SqlDbType.Date).Value = d1.Value
    command.Parameters.Add("@d2", SqlDbType.Date).Value = d2.Value
    Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(command)
    adapter.Fill(table)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = table
End Sub
```

when I randomize the dates in this case only on Saturdays, if there is no correspondence of data, I would like it to pass beyond the next Saturday, until existing data is found with that date (Saturday).

Comment: I have no idea at all what that second paragraph means. Please try to explain more clearly, perhaps with some examples.

Comment: No one should need to read the comments to understand the question. Edit your question to make it clear.

Comment: My code only looks for me on Saturdays, but randomly also looks for Saturdays that are not present in my table, for example Saturday 2nd November, I have no data, I would like it to skip those dates that have no data to display in DataGridView. So when randomizing the datatimepichker, I would like it to skip those dates or Saturdays that don't match anything in my table and then move on to the next Saturday, until it finds the date that matches a whole row with existing data and date.